# What's the best approach to create duplicated pages with paginated posts?

Tags: posts

what I need to do is everytime I create a post serve the original post without nextpage tags, and create a separated version with the nextpage tags (I would rel=canonical to the original post for seo purposes).
What do you think is the best approach to create this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Easier way would be to use a $_GET parameter (which don't change the autogenerated canonical address wordpress uses) and the [content_pagination](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/content_pagination/) filter like this:

```
add_filter( 'content_pagination', function($pages){
    if ( in_the_loop() && (isset($_GET['onepage']) ){
        $pages = [ join( '', $pages ) ];
    }

    return $pages;
} );
```

Happy Coding.